# Impossible IndexOutOfBound happening on ArrayList.get(). Any clue?

Tags: java

I've got a very strange error, that would like to share with you.

I've the following code (simplified):

```
public ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
public void doSomething() {
  int size = al.size();
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    if (al.get(i) != null) {
      System.out.println(al.get(i));
      String sPath = al.get(i);
      File fFile = new File(sPath);
      fFile.delete(); // Simplified. It has some error checking
    }
  }
}
```

I have one error, saw in the production environment:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at MYCLASS.soSomething(MICLASS.java:1944)
    [...]
```

Line 1944 is `if (al.get(i) != null) {`.

What! How can it raise IndexOutOfBound?!

The problem is that the error does not reproduce. I've been able to raise it only once in the dev environment, but trying to reproduce it was not possible (it dit not raise again)... so no way to look for a pattern in the error.

So my only option is simple: read the code and use the brain.

So I browse the code of `java.util.ArrayList.get()`:

```
public class ArrayList<E> [...]{
  public E get(int index) {
    RangeCheck(index);
    return (E) elementData[index];
  }
  private void RangeCheck(int index) {
    if (index >= size)
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: "+index+", Size: "+size);
  }
}
```

So it throws the exception because `index >= size`... How is it possible? The `for()` sweeps from `0` to `size-1`... It is impossible! It cannot raise the error!

Wait a second! This code is not thread-safe. Maybe another thread is calling `clear()` or `remove*()` on the ArrayList... Studying the code, it is not possible. So I run it, set a breakpoint on line 1944 and watch the threads in that moment, and effectively, the other running threads have nothing to do with this issue.

Any other clue?

Kernnigan & Pike: "Debugging [...]Something impossible occurred, and the only solid information is that it really did occur."

Comment: I suspect the bug is in "// It actually does some more things". Please post more code - *ideally* a short but complete program. For example: do you ever modify the array list within that loop? Do you ever modify `i` within the loop?

Comment: Are you sure that there really is no other thread messing with the list? If the code you have shown is complete, that looks like the only explanation. Or you "simplified" the code sample too much.

Comment: This is really a test to see if we can read minds and figure out what goes here `// It actually does some more things`. I vote this question for the most questionable question of the day award. To be believed.

Comment: "// It actually does some more things" does not modify the Arraylist. I'll edit the post to show some more code.

Comment: Jon, I cannot send a "short but complete program", because a short-but-complete-program works as expected. The method is not much more complicate than that, really. A couple of layers of calls, but it finally does was is described. I do not modify neither `i` nor `al` within the loop.

Comment: Thilo, that's the first thing I though of (since the àl`is publicly available), but I've tried setting a breakpoint on that line. Then, Eclipse shows the running threads, and the threads are awt-eventqueue-0 ("my" thread), the standard java threads, and two other UI threads that have nothing to do with this piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

I see the following candidates how this happens:

- something in your loop changes the value of `i`.
- something in your loop changes the size of `al`, possibly something removing elements.
- something is replacing your collection with a different collection.
- I have seen cases where the loop was constructed in a way so the body gets even executed once in the case of an empty collection. Although that seems unlikely with a for loop as described.

An idea for debugging this: replace the list with your own implementation which logs every access to it, and delegating all the real functionality to a standard implementation.

If needed it can print the stack trace of an freshly created exception in order to identify the place it is called from. It can even throw an exception when it gets accessed from a different thread.

Comment: All of these can probably be prevented/detected by using a foreach loop (and getting rid of `i`).

Comment: if i isn't needed for anything else that would be the right thing to do. But it solves only the first and the last kind of problem.

Comment: I'd definately try what Thilo recommended. It has the advantage of determining if you change the data you traverse during the loop as the construct can fire a ConcurrentModificationException when you try to change what you're currently looping over.

Comment: It also helps with problems 2 and 3: If you remove elements, you will get a ConcurrentModificationException (so at least you know what is going on), and swapping to a different collection in the loop will not affect the iteration at all.

Comment: Neither `i` nor `al` are modified within the loop. Sorry.

Comment: Thilo, I've tried overwritting `clear()` and `remove*()`, and my tests shows them being called only from the code in `doSomething()`. However, as said, I've not been able to make it fail on the dev environment (it has failed only once on production and once in dev (in front of my eyes)), so maybe if the error condition is given, it would call them.

Comment: Jens, I had though on (and tested) some other thread removing elements from `al`... but I had not tough on those threads _replacing_ `al`, since it is public. Good idea, I'll explore that.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone is suggesting that you're removing elements from the Array.  The solution to your problem is to use an `Iterator`, which allows you to iterate through an entire Collection, but still allow you to modify that Collection.

Comment: Thanks. That's probably the best solution for the Exception not to raise... but it may just hide another problem. But I do not want just to avoid the exception (`try{...}catch(){}` would do that), but know what the hell is happening to throw an error that should not raise.

Comment: Looping through an Array while removing items will cause an exception - this is expected and the reason for creating an iterator in the first place.

Comment: I still think it is a bad idea, just a way to "sweep thrash below the carpet" (is this expression used in English?). I'll explain. When a record is deleted in the DB, a file is added to `al`. Later, on COMMIT, `doSomething()` is called and the files are deleted. Using an `Iterator` would prevent the error, but... Who is modifying my `al` while I do COMMIT? If any thread is doing so, I would like to find it, not just skip the error.

Comment: You've simplified a lot of your code.  Agreed, if you are not modifying your `al`, then this shouldn't be happening.  But I presume you're emptying `a1` at some point, yes?  So, you are modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably remove elements from your `ArrayList` in your for loop, therefore decrementing its original size which is used to exit this loop!

Answer (score 0):

How sure are you that your simplified code exactly replicates the production code?  To my mind it's impossible for your simplified code to raise `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because the list is empty so the for loop should never be processed.  Are you modifying the contents of the array list in the loop?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does replicate the real code. After a couple of different calls, it just deleted the files passed in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that another thread is modifying the list while your code above is scanning it.

If you want something better than guesses, you need to show us either the relevant production code, or create a simplified version that actually exhibits the same problem when you run it.

---

> Studying the code, it is not possible.

Clearly is **is** possible, otherwise you wouldn't have observed it.

Comment: Stephen, have you read the full post? The quote at the end? ;-) However, guesses is the only thing I expected, since even me, running the tests once and again, have seen it failing only once.

Comment: Yes I did read the quote.  It is meant to be humorous.  From your comment, I'd say that this has all of the hallmarks of a threading / synchronization bug.  In other words, you've missed something critical in your studying of the code.  If you can't create a SSCCE, there's little more we can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for the answers. Most of the suggestions are based on:

A) The loop is modifying `al` or `i`.

B) Another thread is modifying `al`.

c) Another thread is *replacing* `al`.

Since I know A is not the case, I'll bet that in some cases another thread is modifying/replacing `al`. Since I cannot make it fail in a pattern, such thread may be running only in certain situations, such as error conditions. While the code in the loop is pretty simple, the application is not at all small, with abuse of singletons and getter/setters, and it hardens the debugging, so I wouldn't be surprised of it.

That's the same that I suspected (except C, that I had not though of), but you confirmed that this is the only possible cause. Thanks for your help.